# How do I access sharepoint folder requiring credentials using VBA?

Tags: windows, vba, excel, sharepoint, filesystemobject

I need to access folder on a SharePoint using VBA however the SharePoint requires Windows credentials and I do not want to map to a network drive.

When I run the code initially I get a 'path not found' error. If I open the SharePoint location in Windows Explorer it asks for my login, then when I go back to VBA the code works. I don't want to have to paste the file location into Windows Explorer every time I run it.

The code looks something like this:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder("\\this.location\foo\bar")
```

Is there any way to make VBA realise the path does actually exist and to prompt for the user's credentials?

Thanks.